# Find two smallest value inputs

Tags: java, algorithm

The instructions are: "Ask the user for the following information, in this order:

- A terminating value (real number). The user will enter this value again later, to indicate that he or she is finished providing input.
- A sequence of real numbers. Keep asking for numbers until the terminating value is entered.
- Compute and output the smallest and second-smallest real number, in that order. It is possible for the smallest and second-smallest numbers to be the same (if the sequence contains duplicate numbers)."

I uploaded my code and the grading software gave me a zero saying the program is not consistent with the assignment, however, when testing my code it runs just as required for the assignment. Any feedback as to why this may happen would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public class TwoSmallest
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double terminator;
        System.out.print ("Please enter a terminating value: ");
        terminator = IO.readDouble();

        double lowest1;
        double lowest2;
        System.out.println("Please enter sequence of numbers:");
        lowest1 = IO.readDouble();
        while (lowest1 == terminator)
        {
            IO.reportBadInput();
            lowest1 = IO.readDouble();
        }
        lowest2 = IO.readDouble();
        while (lowest2 == terminator)
        {
            IO.reportBadInput();
            lowest2 = IO.readDouble();
        }
        double input;
        do
        {
            input = IO.readDouble();
            if (input < lowest1)
            {
                if(lowest2 < lowest1)
                    lowest2 = lowest1;
                lowest1 = input;
            }
            else if (input < lowest2)
                lowest2 = input;
        }while (input != terminator);

        System.out.println("RESULT: " + lowest1);
        System.out.println("RESULT: " + lowest2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may as him directly if you think he is wrong?

Comment: You are processing the terminator value. Also if the input starts with 2, 1, you will assign 2 as the lowest number and 1 as the second lowest. And is it guaranteed that at least 2 numbers must be entered before the terminator?

Comment: Because of the flaws Cinnam pointed out, you're probably better off just storing all input values in an array and then calculate the two smallest numbers right before printing them.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I fixed the problem to make sure if in the scenario that 2, 1 is input it will output 1 as the lowest. However, I am having trouble seeing where I am processing the terminator value. I would have used arraylists, but we are not allowed to use import statements.

Comment: @Tom Try the input `0 1 1 0`. The logic in the loop is also wrong - try `10 1 2 -5 10`. You should shift the lowest values without the condition `if (lowest2 < lowest1)`

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, I managed to adjust my code to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two scenarios which are not handled by your solution :

For suppose you have given the sequence of numbers 3,7,1 the result of your code is 1 and 7 not 1 and 3.
It is because you are not changing lowest2 value when input <  lowest1.

If your input is 3,1,7 where first number is lowest1, second number is lowest2 and then input variable value is 7 then the condition (input < lowest1) is false, so there will be no swapping of lowest1 and lowest2 values and the result will be 3 and 1 instead of 1 and 3.